# HTML5 required attribute and two submits

Tags: html, forms, validation, required

I have a form with a required input field and two submit buttons:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text1" value="<?php echo $temp1 ?>"  required>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="submit" name="auto">Auto</button>
</form>
```

What i need is to ignore the "required" when a user clicks the "Auto" button and make it work only for the "Submit".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `formnovalidate` in your button.

> The formnovalidate attribute can be used to make submit buttons that do not trigger the constraint validation.

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text1" value="<?php echo $temp1 ?>"  required>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="submit" name="auto" formnovalidate>Auto</button>
</form>
```

For reference: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formnovalidate.asp)

Comment: I totally forgot about this "formnovalidate" attribute. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question you want the required to removed or disabled when the submit button is clicked? Since it  is an attribute all you need do is remove it from your list of attributes in the input.Hope this answers you question.